# C Processing Input

Tags: c, string

I have a question regarding a C program. I want to take in 3 arguments in a `scanf` statement. Ex:    Value1 Operation Value2.
I am currently using this line of code to do this.

```
scanf("%s %s %s",firstString,secondString,thirdString);
```

However, the problem is that I want the user to be able to type quit and end the program. But When this code is ran the program requires me to type in a value for each string. It will not allow me to just type quit. How can I fix this problem? I only want to be able to type quit without the program requiring me to input something for each string it expects.

Comment: Enter a single string with `fgets` and then apply `sscanf` to that string once you know it does not say "quit". Watch out for the trailing `newline` in the string.

Comment: in that case don't use `scanf`. `scanf` can only be used if the input format is expected. Use `fgets` and parse the string yourself.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information, it was really just a concept question that I didn't feel like hassling you with code. @Whoever said to just put an if statement after the initial scanf, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though being already answered, see a solution that reads in a complete line and then interprets up to 3 commands:

```
int main (void)
{
    #define BUFFERSIZE 100
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    char *commands[3];
    printf("Enter your commands (quit to exit): \n");
    int quit = 0;
    while(!quit && fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE , stdin) ) /* break with ^D or ^Z */
    {
        char* command = strtok(buffer," \n");
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            commands[i] = command;
            if (command && strcmp(command, "quit")==0) {
                quit = 1;
            }
            command = strtok(NULL," \n");
        }
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            const char* str = commands[i];
            if (!str)
                break;
            else
                printf("command %d:%s\n",i,str);
        }
    }
    printf("program ended");
    return 0;
}
```

Input/Output test:

```
Enter your commands (quit to exit): 
herbert anton friedrich
command 0:herbert
command 1:anton
command 2:friedrich
joseph sepp
command 0:joseph
command 1:sepp
anton quit
command 0:anton
command 1:quit
program ended
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop like:

```
char s[3][50];
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    scanf("%49s", s[i]);
    if( strcmp(s[i], "quit") == 0)
        break;
}
```

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/wBT2Lj).

Comment: C does not have a `string` data type.

Comment: @Marievi Ok, seems like i misinterpreted the needs... Maybe I will try a different approach later

Comment: @Marievi that makes no difference whether the strings are entered on one line, three lines, or two+one lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think another approach is to specify a menu to the user:

```
while (strcmp(s[i], "quit"!=0){
printf("What do you want to do?");
scanf ("%s",option);

if ( strcmp(option,"1") ==0))
scanf("%s %s %s",firstString,secondString,thirdString);
}
```